# Get name of button onPress in react native

Tags: button, react-native, onpress

I have two buttons that both call the same onPress function.   In the callback I want to be able to differentiate between which was pressed.

```
<MKRadioButton
   title='A' 
   group={this.radioGroup}
   onPress={this._toggle}
 />

<MKRadioButton
   title='B' 
   group={this.radioGroup}
   onPress={this._toggle}
 />
```

then the call

```
_toggle(event) {
    //what should go here to figure out if title A or B was called?
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One solution is to pass that info as a parameter:

```
<MKRadioButton
  title='A' 
  group={this.radioGroup}
  onPress={(event) => this._toggle(event, 'A')}
/>
```

The callback would then use that parameter

```
_toggle(event, buttonId) {
  // Use buttonId
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Another solution is a parent component that always returns the title prop:

```
class RadioParent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MKRadioButton
        title={this.props.title} 
        group={this.props.radioGroup}
        onPress={(event) => this.props.onPress(event, this.props.title)}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, are you referring to the title prop being A as well as the callback parameter? Is there something else not stated in the question you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yeah I have like 30 of these buttons so there will have to be a lot of extra text and it'll make it hard to update in the future.  Ideally I want to get  a reference to the button that was clicked and find the title that way

Comment: You could solve that by creating a parent component (if extending `MKRadioButton`'s API isn't an option) that always returns the given `title` prop as the second parameter in `onPress`, similar to the code above.

Comment: Added an example of a parent component. Does that meet your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

To improve performance, you can bind the event handler in the constructor to have it rendered only once

[Facebook tip](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html) (at the bottom of the page)

> We generally recommend binding in the constructor or using the property initializer syntax, to avoid this sort of performance problem.

```js
class MKRadioButtonWrapper extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.buttonPressed = this.buttonPressed.bind(this);
  }

  buttonPressed(){
    this.props.onPress(this.props.title);
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <MKRadioButton
       title={this.props.title}
       group={this.props.group}
       onPress={buttonPressed}
     />
    );
  }
}
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this._toggle = this._toggle.bind(this);
  }

  _toggle(title) {
    //do what you want with the title
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <MKRadioButtonWrapper
           title='A' 
           group={this.radioGroup}
           onPress={this._toggle}
         />

        <MKRadioButtonWrapper
           title='B' 
           group={this.radioGroup}
           onPress={this._toggle}
         />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```