# React-Native Expo issue with TextInput

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, expo

I'm creating a simple event tracker app using React-Native, Redux, React-Navigation and Expo and I'm having a bit of trouble with a fairly trivial part.

I have a form screen where you enter the event name, date and other information. I'm using `<TextInput/>` to enter the event's name but it won't to the `onChange` event, only `onChangeText`. Additionally when I use `onChange` event, the **Back** button on the navigation becomes unresponsive and the cursor remains only in the TextInput no matter where I click

I'm having another problem related to memory which causes the simulator to load longer and longer after each successive build, and become unresponsive after a few loads. My mobile expo app also crashes occasionally. I have a somewhat vague feeling that these 2 issues are related but I'm totally lost as to what the issue may be. Basically the Exponent simulator doubles in memory usage every time i save a file.

Here is the the `CreateEventScreen.js` looks like at the moment, I'm going to convert it to Redux as soon as I resolve the onChange issue.

```
export default class CreateEvent extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      date: new Date(),
      repeatAnnually: false,
      showDatePicker: false,
      wallPaperSource: null
    };
    this.toggleSelectWallPaper = this._toggleSelectWallPaper.bind(this);
    this.handleChange=this._handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Create New Event'
  }

  _handleToggleSwitch = () => this.setState(state => ({
    repeatAnnually: !this.state.repeatAnnually
  }));

  /* THIS IS NOT WORKING */
  _handleChange = (event) => {
    console.log(event);
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    })
  }

  _onDateChange = (date) => this.setState(state => ({
    date: date
  }));

  _toggleSelectWallPaper = async() => {
    let result;
    try {
      result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        allowEditing: true,
        aspect: [4, 3]
      });
    } catch (e) {
        result = null;
    }

    if(!result.cancelled){
      this.setState({
        wallPaperSource: result.uri
      });
    }

  }

  _renderDatePicker(){
    if(this.props.showDatePicker){
      return (
          <DatePickerIOS
            date={this.state.date}
            mode="date"
            onDateChange={this._onDateChange}
          />
      )
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  render(){
    const { onClick, toggleDatePicker, showDatePicker } = this.props
    let { wallPaperSource } = this.state;
    return(
      <View>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          name="name"
          placeholder="Event Name"
          value={this.state.name}
          /* THIS IS NOT WORKING */
          onChange={this._handleChange}
          /* This works but not ideal for redux integration */
          // onChange={(event) => this.setState({'name': event.target.value})}  
        />
        <View style={styles.eventDetailsContainer}>
          <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
            <Text>Repeat Annually</Text>
            <Switch
              onValueChange={this._handleToggleSwitch}
              value={this.state.repeatAnnually}
            />
          </View>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={e => {
            e.preventDefault()
            toggleDatePicker(showDatePicker)
          }}>
            <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
              <Text>Select Date</Text>
              <Text>{this.state.date.toLocaleDateString()}</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View>
            {this._renderDatePicker()}
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.eventDetailsContainer}>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.toggleSelectWallPaper}>
            <View style={styles.itemContainer}>
              <Text>Wallpaper</Text>
              { this.state.wallPaperSource  ?
                <Image source={{ uri: wallPaperSource }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}/>
                 : null
              }
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <Button
          style={styles.submitBtn}
          onPress={e => {
            e.preventDefault()
            if(!this.state.name.trim()){
              return
            }
            onClick(this.state)
          }}
          color="#1e90ff"
          title="Create Event"
        />
    </View>
    )
  }
}
```

package.json -

```
{
  "name": "floss-evens",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Hello Expo!",
  "author": null,
  "private": true,
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^18.0.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-18.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.3",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.7.2"
  }
}
```

Any help or feedback would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't wish to use `onChangeText`? Just a guess, but the event object might be huge, and simply logging it might halt other js execution. If you remove `console.log`, does that resolve the unresponsiveness problem?

Comment: My rational behind not using `OnChangeText` is that it's not very reusable in the sense that I would have to manually set the key that's being updated. Additionally, i think it would get more complicated when I implement redux into it this component.

You were correct about removing the `console.log`! Thank you for that. The `onChange` event works. However now i'm logging the target `console.log('target', event.target)` and all it's giving me is "47" for any input.

Comment: All right. That's also possible to solve by supplying additional parameters to `onChangeText`: `onChangeText={(value) => this._handleChange(value, 'keyName')}`. A redux integration should not change this logic, only make the information flow chain longer.

Comment: Yeah I figured i'd be able to do it with `onChangeText` but I'd prefer to do it dynamically, rather than passing in a static value. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event object supplied to `onChange` is large, and will halt other js execution if logged. Simply remove `console.log(event);`.

When using `onChange`, the input value can be retrieved using `event.nativeEvent.text`. This is not how you're supposed to capture input values, though. The correct approach is to use `onChangeText`.

`TextInput` does not have a property called *name*, that will simply be ignored.

```
// This will not be defined
const name = target.name;
```

You can supply additional parameters to `_handleChange` to accomplish the intended action:

```
onChangeText={(value) => this._handleChange(value, 'keyName')}
```

If you want to handle this automatically e.g. for a large number of inputs, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44423132/get-name-of-button-onpress-in-react-native).