# how to access property of React Native tag or element in onPress function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to access React Native element property in onPress function i tried it with event.target and ReactNativeComponentTree but it not works , i want to access audioPath property in Onpress function

```
  <Ionicons
  name="ios-play"
  size={35}
  color={this.state.playAudio ? "red" : "blue"}
  style={{
      left: 90,
      position: "relative",
      shadowColor: "#000",
      shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
      shadowOpacity: 0.5,
      backgroundColor: "transparent"
  }}
  audioPath= {audioPath}
  onPress={this.audioPathFunction.bind(this)}
  />
```

Comment: Please mention all scenario

Comment: Actually I want to render multiple ioniIcons but problem is that all have the same value I want the ioniIcons to keep its own value of audiopath ,the method you ask give same value to all the ioniIcons when I render multiple time

Comment: So you have multiple audioPath?

Comment: yes , actually it's a  voice chat app in which each recording have a different path ,

Comment: You have array of audioPath?

Comment: @WaqarAmjad Check out my answer and let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <Ionicons
  name="ios-play"
  size={35}
  color={this.state.playAudio ? "red" : "blue"}
  style={{
      left: 90,
      position: "relative",
      shadowColor: "#000",
      shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
      shadowOpacity: 0.5,
      backgroundColor: "transparent"
  }}
  audioPath= {audioPath}
  onPress={()=> this.audioPathFunction(audioPath)}
  />
```

Depends. you can access it inside , if its state variable/class variable u can access it anywhere even inside onPress function. If its only available in render() use pointer functions like above (which is not a good way)

Comment: Actually I want to render multiple ioniIcons but problem is that all have the same value I want the ioniIcons to keep its own value of audiopath ,the method you ask give same value to all the ioniIcons when I render multiple time

Answer (score 0):

*Actually I want to render multiple ioniIcons but problem is that all have the same value I want the ioniIcons to keep its own value of audiopath ,the method you ask give same value to all the ioniIcons when I render multiple time*

For this, you can create an array of `audioPath` and iterate over it to create multiple `Ionicons` like,

```
conat audioPathArray = [audiopath1,audiopath2,audiopath3];
```

Now you can iterate over array,

```
{audioPathArray.map(audiopath=>{
  <Ionicons
    name="ios-play"
    size={35}
    color={this.state.playAudio ? "red" : "blue"}
    style={{
      left: 90,
      position: "relative",
      shadowColor: "#000",
      shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
      shadowOpacity: 0.5,
      backgroundColor: "transparent"
    }}
    audioPath= {audioPath}
    onPress={()=> this.audioPathFunction(audioPath)}
   />
 })
}
```

This way you will get as many `Ionicons` as `audioPath`'s, and clicking on each `Ionicons` will give you different `audioPath`.

And finally your function,

```
audioPathFunction = (audioPath) => {
   console.log(audioPath)
}
```

Comment: is there not any way to access React native element property because the method you tell will 
make my work complex because my chat contain audio and text both 

just like in below example i want to get the value of name by onPress 
<Button

name ={'xyz'}
onPress={()=>{

}}

/>

Comment: @WaqarAmjad If you want to use the button, you can wrap the OnPress function around the icon using touchableOpacity.

Comment: So are you able to render multiple `Ionicons` with different `audioPath`?

Comment: @ravibagul91 with For Each loop yes i can render multiple Ionicons with different audioPath but that's not my desire output it make my work complex to do , simple thing tell me , is it possible to access element property just like event.target.value

Comment: I think No. here is the good source of info - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7892

Comment: Also check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44423132/get-name-of-button-onpress-in-react-native